# What does “triumphant” mean?

Tags: word-usage

> 1. This is a story of Vienna *triumphant*.
> 2. Whilst many now feared Napoleon’s expansionist ambitions, he was welcome when he rode into Vienna *triumphant*.

As far as I know, *triumphant* is merely an adjective, but the use in the two examples got me totally confused. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In English it is most usual to place an adjective before the noun that it modifies - a cold day, a triumphant rider, but rarely you will find adjectives placed after the noun - they are said to be postnominal or postpositive. These chiefly appear in a restricted set of situations. Certain adjectives are found more often, and triumphant is one.

His formidable enemies defeated him on almost every side, yet in the end he emerged triumphant.

> triumphant
>
> ADJECTIVE
>
> 1 Having won a battle or contest; victorious.
>
> ‘two of their triumphant Cup team’
>
> postpositive ‘a comic fairy tale about innocence triumphant’

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/triumphant

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postpositive_adjective

Comment: thanks, and could you be so kind as to tell me what the sentence “a comic......innocence triumphant” means?

Comment: As for my second example, it is *he* that *triumphant* modifies, but they are so far from each other, is that also a postpositive case?

Comment: The usage "he rode into Vienna triumphant" doesn't feel like a postnominal to me, and it fits into a very common pattern: "he arrived elated", "he left besotted", "she rode naked". I've no idea what the grammatical construct is called.